# How to update global JSON field in angular js with JSON objects from different views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have defined a global JSON object. I want to write a function that allows the user to click a button and the master JSON object gets an ujpdate.

```
$scope.masterJsonObj=[];
$Scope.myfunction=function($scope){
$scope.masterJsonObj= $scope.formdataJson + $scope.secondJsonObj + $scope.thirdJsonObj
```

final json object should look like this

```
[
  {
  fName: "firstname",
  lName: "lastname",
  id: "userId",         
  secondJsonObj : [
                {
                     bankAccount: "some bank",
                     bankAccountNumber: "12334",                       
                     Status: "true"
                },
                {
                    bankAccount: "some bank2",
                    bankAccountNumber: "212334",                       
                    Status: "false" 
                }],
   thirdJsonObj[{                
                    addrone: "some treet",
                    addr2: "house number" 
              }]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $rootScope as you can simply inject it into any controller and change values in this scope.

$rootScope is a parent of all scopes so values in rootscope will be accessible in all controllers.